# C# DateTime - RFC 3339 format

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, rfc3339

I am trying to generate RFC 3339 compliant date strings (ie. '2008-03-19T00:00:00.0000000-04:00') however I seem to be having an issue with the offset being invalid. I am using the following:

```
private string GetDate(DateTime DateTime)
{
    DateTime UtcDateTime = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeToUtc(DateTime);
    return XmlConvert.ToString(UtcDateTime, XmlDateTimeSerializationMode.Utc);
}
```

but this returns me with a value such as **"1977-02-03T05:00:00Z"**

I have also attempted using a specific format such as

```
 utcDateTime.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
```

But with the same results.

---

See this existing reference: [How do I parse and convert DateTime's to the RFC 3339 date-time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017/how-do-i-parse-and-convert-datetimes-to-the-rfc-3339-date-time-format)

Comment: Your `UtcDateTime` is UTC, then why do you expect a time-zone different from 0?

Comment: @CodeInChaos - My understanding was the -04:00 of 2008-03-19T00:00:00.0000000-04:00 represented the Utc Offset

Comment: Yes, since your DataTime uses the UTC-timezone your UTC offset should be 0. And for that the RFC specifies short notation `Z`. At least that's what I remember. Has been some time since I read that RFC.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are converting your data to UTC, so its timezone offset to UTC is 0:00. The RFC defines a convenient notation for UTC dates, the suffix `Z`. So this looks like a valid data-string to me.

Answer (score 1):

I used this approach for **.NET 6**:

```
public static class DateTimeExtensions
{
     public static string ToRFC3339(this DateTime date)
     {
         return date.ToUniversalTime().ToString("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.fffK");
     }
}
```