# Displaying Google Calendar API v3 Events dateTime in Xamarin C#

Tags: c#, datetime, xamarin, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to take events from Google Calendar and display them in a listView for Xamarin.Forms.

Google Calendar uses an RFC3339 format when you call start.dateTime the format is yyyy-mm-dd.
I'm trying to do a string day of the week format (Mon Jan 1, 2018) similar to .Net DateTime.ToLongDateString Method.

My Code so far is this:

```
namespace TheFirstAcademy.ViewModels{
class EventListViewModel
{
    public List<SchoolEvent> SchoolEvents { get; set; }
    public SchoolCalendar SelectedCalendar { get; set; }


    public EventListViewModel(SchoolCalendar selectedcalendar)
    {
        SelectedCalendar = selectedcalendar;
        SchoolEvents = GetSchoolEvents();

    }

    public List<SchoolEvent> GetSchoolEvents()
    {
        // Create Google Calendar API service.
        var service = new CalendarService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
        {
            ApiKey = "Key",
            ApplicationName = "TFA Calendar Mobile App",
        });

        // Define parameters of request.
        EventsResource.ListRequest request = service.Events.List(SelectedCalendar.SchoolCalId);
        request.TimeMin = DateTime.Now;
        request.ShowDeleted = false;
        request.SingleEvents = true;
        request.MaxResults = 10;
        request.OrderBy = EventsResource.ListRequest.OrderByEnum.StartTime;

        // List events.
        Events events = request.Execute();
        List<SchoolEvent> schoolEvents = new List<SchoolEvent>();

        if (events.Items != null && events.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var eventItem in events.Items)
            {
                string when = eventItem.Start.DateTime.ToString();
                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(when))
                {
                    when = eventItem.Start.Date;
                }

                schoolEvents.Add(new SchoolEvent() {
                    EventTitle = eventItem.Summary,
                    EventDescription = eventItem.Description,
                    EventStartTime = when,
                    EventEndTime = eventItem.End.Date
                });
            }
        }
        return schoolEvents;
    }
}
```

}

This will eventually get displayed in a ListView for iOS and Android using Xamarin.Forms. The Event for a calendar would look something like this:

[Event Name]

[Event Location]

Starts: Fri May 25, 2018 12:00 PM

Ends: Sat May 26, 2018 12:00 PM

Some references I have been found:
Google Calendar v3 Events info
https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events

RFC to dateTime (not sure if this is the right direction). 
[How do I parse and convert a DateTime to the RFC 3339 date-time format?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17017/how-do-i-parse-and-convert-a-datetime-to-the-rfc-3339-date-time-format)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the conversion by using. DateTime.Parse()

I converted the eventItem.Start.Date (which is a string)to DateTime using DateTime.Parse(). Then I converted the DateTime to string ("ddd MMM dd, yyyy").

Probably basic stuff Maybe this will help someone.